# RxJava retry on failure thrown inside of doOnNext

Tags: android, rx-java2

AIM: Refresh an adapter when something changes, but only when the user has stopped scrolling the list.

I am trying to throw an error in `doOnNext` so that I can then wait and retry again. However, this isn't working. I can see that the exception is being thrown, but `retryWhen` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
someObservable()
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .debounce(650, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .doOnNext(o -> {
      if (isListScrolling()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
      }
    })
  .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
  .subscribe(o -> refreshListNow());
```

*UPDATE*:
`someObservable` is a `Subject` (Bus) that I'm observing UI events on.

See my comment below, as it seems `retry()` here won't work how one would expect (i.e. retry does not cause the source to automatically re-emit the last value, unless I was perhaps to use a `BehaviorSubject` - which isn't suitable here).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what value is emmited. So I'll just make it a string for this example. Checking the scrolling state inside doOnNext is too late, since they can not be propagated back to retryWhen. You can simply use flatMap to throw an error instead.

```
Observable.just("someValue")
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .debounce(650, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap((Func1<String, Observable<?>>) s -> {
            if (isListScrolling()) {
                // Still scrolling, pass error so we can retry in the next step
                return Observable.error(new Exception());
            }

            // Not scrolling, we can continue
            return Observable.just("someValue");
        })
        .retry()
        .subscribe(o -> refreshListNow());
```

Comment: I've tried the above variant, however now the code in 'retryWhen' seems to be triggering even when there's no error, and then the subscription seems to die out completely.

Comment: I should add that the 'observable' is a Subject (a bus)... perhaps that changes things?

Comment: two minor things - `Observable.just(null)` won't work in RxJava 2, and I'd use a `.map` instead of a `.flatMap`. a subject may change things - quoting [RxRelay's project page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay): "Subjects are useful to bridge the gap between non-Rx APIs. However, they are stateful in a damaging way: when they receive an onComplete or onError they no longer become usable for moving data. This is the observable contract and sometimes it is the desired behavior. Most times it is not."

Comment: @ahmedre yes I updated my question, however I am under the impression that a retry always re-subscribes to the immediate source it's observing, and that would be the emitter from .map(..), perhaps I still don't fully understand how this should work.

Comment: I've changed retryWhen to retry since retry is more appropriate for this scenario anyway. Retry will resubscribe your subscription if an error occurs. This shoul have been the case before edit too. Did you try to comment out the line that throws exception? Are you sure you don't have any mistake in isListScrolling function? try returning always true and alway false and see the difference.

Comment: I've tried everything, including the new suggested edit. Sadly nothing I try works. You can replace isListScrolling with 1==1 and it still won't work (since isListScrolling is a contrived example here, the actual code is much simpler where the condition is checking a boolean flag).

Comment: It turns out this isn't possible, see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5028

retry() is Flow dependent, and since in our case the Subject is acting as a UI event bus, once retry re-subscribes, it sits there and waits for the bus to emit a new event. What's important to note is that retry, as the name implies, does not automatically 'retry' the last emitted value, it simply re-subscribes and lets the source re-emit, if it can. The solution is to not rely on retry but to either re-emit manually or to use a Valve to pause / start the flow.